# Set DataContext in default constructor AND after event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following code in my form default constructor where I set the DataContext by passing two parameters to my View Model. I also set one property to true by default which sets a checkbox to checked on form load.

```
DataCompareVM dcvm = new DataCompareVM(dataset1FullPath, dataset2FullPath);
dcvm.SortVariables = true;
DataContext = dcvm;
```

The problem is that the two parameters are null on form startup so I get the following error: "Application error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path".

I could move the code to after the variables are assigned data and it will work then, but the SortVariables bool will only be assigned then and not at startup.

edit: I can't simply set the checkbox to checked in the XAML because it is already bound:

```
IsChecked="{Binding SortVariables}
```

How do I get around this issue?

Comment: Why do you need to set the checkbox to checked here? Can't you just set it in the XAML? `IsChecked="True"`

Comment: See my edit, I already have the checkbox bound.

Comment: I see, what's the problem with assigning `SortVariables` after `dataset1FullPath` and `dataset2FullPath` are assigned?

Comment: Where do you get the exception and which properties are null?

Comment: The exception is in the first line of code I posted above. dataset1FullPath and dataset2FullPath are both null on form load, which is where that code is.

Comment: Of course you need to set the DataContext for the binding to work...Before you have created an instance of the class there is no binding.

Comment: I want the checkbox to appear checked when the form is loaded, not after the user has assigned data to those variables. It will confuse them if they see the checkbox tick itself after they assign data

Comment: you can create in your model property isChecked(bind to xaml) and set it to true, so when your view appear, checkbox will be checked

Comment: Where is the code/xaml that actually produces the exception? Might be better to handle the null paths without error instead of playing around with the portion of the program that works for itself to hide the problems in the part that is not working.

Comment: There is not enough context here to know what the _right_ approach is. Any variety of changes would fix the issue. That said, it's my opinion that you should change the VM type so the constructor is parameterless and those values are initialized as properties later. Or possibly set with a method. Alternatively, just initialize the VM later as you mention. It's not clear why it would be a problem to not initialize the `SortVariables` property later as well, since without a VM I'd think that property would be useless (and unavailable).

Answer (score 0):

> I want the checkbox to appear checked when the form is loaded, not after the user has assigned data to those variables. It will confuse them if they see the checkbox tick itself after they assign data ...

Well, then you will of course need to move the `SortVariables` to another class and use this one as a temporary `DataContext`:

```
var temp = new { SortVariables = true };
DataContext = temp;
```

You cannot bind to a property of an object that doesn't exist...

Comment: Would this solution mean I need to have another DataContext for the other two variables?

Comment: Once you have initialized your data and created the DataCompareVM object you can re-set the DataContext to it...but again you can't use the class before you have created an instance of it. This is *very* basic.

Answer (score 0):

Set the fallback value to true so when the datacontext is null it will be checked

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value, FallbackValue=True}">Yourcheckbox</CheckBox>
```